# Load library from specific folder

Tags: php

I have a few extensions, which use the same Library class. Library comes in package with each extension and, of course, it is not always up to date. Code is simple:

```
class Library {
 function1 (){
  ...
 }

 function2 (){
  ...
 }
}
```

Let's say we have 2 extensions: one have older version of Library, one - newer. In newer Library a new functions are introduced (function3() and function4()). The task is simple: I need to load Library class from specific folder to be able to use new functions. By default, when both extensions are active on the same page, it loads Library class from extension, which comes first.

I can't seem to find the best solution to achieve this. I know about namespaces (yet never used them before), but they require changes to Library files. I need to have "namespace ExtensionName;" at the beginning of library.php.

Is there any way to avoid ANY extension specific changes to Library files?

Would be nice to just load a bunch of functions from specific file, pack them in some dynamically named class and then initialize it.

**UPDATE**

Just to clarify all this. Say, I have two extensions:

Extension 1
Extension 2

Both of them have "system" folder with two system classes:

```
class SystemClassHelper
{
 function addStuff()
 {
  ...
 }
}
```

and

```
SystemClassModel
{
 function getStuff()
 {
  ...
 }
}
```

The only difference is that Extension 2 has newer versions of system classes with additional functions:

```
function addMoreStuff()
{
 ...
}
```

and

```
function getMoreStuff()
{
 ...
}
```

Both extensions extensively use these system classes and can be executed simultaneously. This means, that they both will use system classes from extension, which was executed first. But if Extension 1 is executed first, Extension 2 will trow an error, when new functions are called (there're no new functions in Extension 1, remember?).

The task is simple: I need to load system classes for each extension specifically to be able to utilize new functions, where needed, and I want this to be done without adding namespaces. And, of course, without "cannot redeclare class" error.

For now I just use this in the beginning of each system class:

```
namespace Extension1
```

and

```
namespace Extension2
```

This works, but requires you to constantly make changes to system classes and make sure namespace was added. I want to just copy "system" folder to another extension and load classes directly from this folder.

Comment: do some autoloading

Comment: @DevDonkey wow! What an answer! SUPER helpful!