# Define namespace from constant

Tags: php, namespaces

This might seem a weird question, but is it possible to define namespace by previously defined constant?

Something like this:

```
DEFINE('MYNAMESPACE', 'CoolName');

namespace {MYNAMESPACE};
```

And in the future address namespace the same way:

```
\MYNAMESPACE\ClassName
```

Comment: No, that is not possible.

Comment: I'd start with the question why you'd want to possibly *change* the namespace name based on a constant to begin with…?

Comment: @deceze To make as less changes to library files as possible. Having dynamic namespace name would be good. Any way besides constant? Or we have to directly define it?

Comment: Having a dynamic namespace would be *bad* for anyone writing code against your library… Namespaces are only intended to reduce name clashes by making your names unique. Just choose a fairly unique namespace and you should have few issues with name clashes, and little to no need to ever change the name. `CompanyName\ProjectName\ModuleName\...` is a decent convention.

Comment: @deceze I already have a distinctive name and nobody will write any code for my library, only me. I'm just too lazy to make too much changes for every extension, which uses this library. I described my task here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39916014/load-library-from-specific-folder But since nobody replied, I decided to go with namespaces. Just wanted to solve the naming problem.